# How to divide the values of a table in google slides by a number using App Script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-slides

I have added a table from a google sheet to google slides using app scripts. However, I want to divide the values of the table by 1000000. Is there a way to divide the table values of the table in google slides by the specified number using app script? Else if there a way to edit the table in google sheets itself before inserting it in the slide?

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, I don't know exactly what task you were trying to accomplish with the script, but the whole idea of writing a separate script to transfer tables between these applications contradicts the main idea - linking data in Google products. Therefore, I'm not asking to see the script code, and I'm not going to discuss exactly how this should be changed. Just insert table data into the slide [**according to the instructions**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7009814?hl=en&sjid=8557746048493713428-EU#zippy=%2Cadd-a-table-from-google-sheets).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

I dare to suggest that you don't really need to really divide numbers by a million - you need to display the contents of the cells as if they were reduced by a million times. Try using the formatting options. Select the desired cells, go to the menu **Format-Number-Custom Number Format** and set the format to `0,,`

[image: Format million]

Each [**comma**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?p=drive_custom_numbers#zippy=%2Ccustom-number-formatting) after the number reduces the displayed bit depth by a thousand:

[image: Help]